# IOException : No Space left on device while Spring loading

Tags: java, spring, perl

I have a jar which will be invoked by a Perl script with some parameters to it. This was working all correct. Recently in one of the servers, getting below exception while the jar is started. There is a graceful recovery from error and the jar completes its task, but in monitoring always shows as failed due to the exception.  This happens intermittently. I am suspecting this is due to some tmp file space issue during Spring Context loading. Any tips would be of much help.

```
system <Invoke the jar command> 1>/tmp/fileNgyQQf 2>/tmp/fileGgYHtz failed: log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:345)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:57)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:315)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:236)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:853)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:172)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at MyMainFile.main(MyMainFile.java:9)
```

Comment: The obvious question: is there any space left on the device? What is using the rest of the space?

Comment: Increase your space for the tmp file system

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this using a VM? you should probably close all your other applications which are using up this space. or, you should increase your RAM size in the VM.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tanveer, but the files for which the No space error is thrown is a tmp file 1>/tmp/fileNgyQQf 2>/tmp/fileGgYHtz . This is not configured in our system. I tried researching if Spring loading or Perl uses any /tmp files. No luck till now. Are you aware of anything like this?

Comment: Nope, I was just throwing stones in air :p